# How to dynamically create svg element and animate a image

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a requirement on page load I need to create an 'Image' attribute and append it to the svg element to start animation. However, I tried to create Image and associated animate element and attach it to the svg element.The image is getting displayed on the page however it is not  getting animated.

Can any one pls help in this.

code  added at
http://jsbin.com/dofun/1/edit?html,js,output

Thanks
Pavan Kumar

Comment: Can you post the code, preferable on a jsfiddle or jsbin. Hard to help when we have nothing to look at!

Comment: ian , code added at   http://jsbin.com/dofun/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Do you want the svg enclosed in an `<image>` tag, or embedded in the html? Your code is using `createElementNS` in conjuction with an svg namespace, but an <image> tag. The appendChild isn't working because there is no element with id of "svg_image".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a duration for an animation is mandatory. If you add

```
animate.setAttribute('dur', '3s');
```

it animates correctly for me provided I add an svg element with an appropriate id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" id="svg_image"/>
</body>
</html>

body, html {
  width : 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
    img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','536');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','536');
img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/SVG_Simple_Logo.svg');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','10');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','10');
img.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'id','image_test');


// animate object

var animate = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','animate');
animate.setAttributeNS(null,'attributeName','x');
animate.setAttributeNS(null,'from',500);
animate.setAttributeNS(null,'to',0);
animate.setAttribute('dur', '3s');
//append animate with image
img.appendChild(animate);

document.getElementById("svg_image").appendChild(img);
```